# How to make an object of type array on javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a problem beacuse I have to save points and I have maked a class of points and I want to do an array of that object to save all the points I get but I dont know how to do it...

This is the function:

```
function Points(x,y){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}
```

I haved the idea of making and array and with the method push introduce the points in the array but I doesn't work beacuse that array is not the type of the object

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create an array of objects.

```
// Create an array named points
var points = [];

// Add elements to the array by pushing them
points.push(new Point(0,2));
```

I changed the name of your constructor function to be **Point** because it is singular.

To get to the points in the array you would loop through like so:

```
var i,l = points.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    console.log("x: "+points[i].x+" y: "+points[i].y);
}
```